# Apache Kafka multiple groups

Tags: apache-kafka, messagebroker

I was reading about Apache Kafka, and I came across it's concept of consumer groups. What I don't understand is its use case. Two different consumers from different groups may read the same message being published. Why would one want to process the same message by two different consumers? Can someone give a practical use case?

Comment: Service 1 send an email, service 2 stores in the database.

Comment: You just summed it up! @Kao

Answer (score 1):

You want to write the data to MySQL *and* to Elastic Search *and* you have an application that reads events and flags some as "errors".

Each one of these use-cases is a separate application that will want to see all the events so they will be separate consumer groups and each will see all messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the most typical scenario in Kafka: an application produces a message and you have two different systems creating two different views on that data (i.e. indexing it in ES and caching it in Redis).

Before Kafka it was common to have your app dual-writing its data into both apps, with all the problems dual writes carry in terms of consistency.

With Kafka you can spin off as many consumer systems in the form of groups and also have parallelisation and fault tolerant having multiple partitions and consumer instances within the group.

Comment: Yes. I was under a stupid assumption that all the consumers will execute the same code. Now it is clear!